# How to check if a specific folder exists and no other file or folder in same path

Tags: linux, bash, shell

We have a situation where we need to run specific set of tests, if a folder is present in a specific path.

If other files are folders present along with this folder, we need to run different set of commands.

```
If {only this folder present}

Run scriptA.sh

Elseif {this folder and other folders/files}

Run scriptB.sh

Fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [ $( ls | wc -l ) -eq 1 && ( -d "$myfolder" ) ]; then 

 scriptA.sh 
else 
 scriptB.sh
fi
```

This confirms only my folder exists, nothing else. Let me know what you all think.

Answer (score 0):

This code will run `scriptA.sh` if `$folder` exist, but if `$other_folder` also exists it'll run `scriptB.sh`:

```
check(){
    [[ -d $folder ]] && {

        [[ -d $other_folder ]] && {
            scriptB.sh
            return
        }

        scriptA.sh
    }
}

check
```

Comment: here the $other_folder can be anything other than $folder, not specific. So how can I do that?

Comment: Just set it like so `other_folder=anything/not/specific`

Answer (score 0):

I am in a parent folder and I create a folder, called "blablabla", and I do a `find` in the "blablabla" folder, this is what I get:

```
Prompt> find ./blablabla
./blablabla
```

I do the same thing for an other folder, which has some contents, and this is what I see:

```
Prompt> find ./Other_folder
./Other_folder
./Other_folder/content_1
...
```

In other words (counting the results):

Folder without content:

```
Prompt> find ./blablabla | wc -l
1
```

Folder with content:

```
Prompt> find ./Other_folder | wc -l
<larger than 1>
```

So, by checking the value of `find ./<your_folder> | wc -l` being one or not, you have a good criteria.